# Выделяется ли в данном случае "прошу" запятыми с двух сторон?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Мне неловко, поэтому(,) прошу, не будьте ко мне строги.

После "поэтому" нужна запятая? Оно ведь относится к части "не будьте..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Мне неловко, поэтому, **прошу**, не будьте ко мне строги.*

Здесь обособляется **вводное слово** "прошу", оно относится не к конкретному слову, а ко всему предложению (к его предикативной основе).

§ 25. Вводные слова и словосочетания http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122

1. Вводные слова и словосочетания выделяются запятыми. Различается несколько основных групп вводных слов по их значению:

(6) вводные слова (сочетания), представляющие собой **призыв к собеседнику**/читателю с целью привлечь его внимание к сообщаемому, внушить определенное отношение к излагаемым мыслям, приводимым фактам и т. д. [видишь (ли), видите (ли), понимаешь (ли), понимаете (ли), знаешь (ли), знаете (ли), **пойми**, поймите, поверьте и др.

Из Нацкоруса:

― Слушай, Володька, шёл бы ты, а? . Уйди, **прошу**…  [Вера Белоусова. Второй выстрел (2000)] [омонимия снята]